# Where do Open Source projects hold their design files?

Tags: open-source, comments, class-diagram

I have seen many opensource project on github, sourceforge etc.
Went through the code on many big projects.

I have never seen ANY design diagrams, from simple class diagrams to sequence diagrams.
Also, many projects (not all) don't actually have any comments on their code.

How is this even possible? No design and some comments only.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the project at hand; design diagrams could be found in the source tree, or on the project's website, or any number of places. There may not even be design diagrams at all -- they're not strictly necessary for software development.

Comment: could you tell us some projects that actually have diagrams?
I cant believe that projects such as firefox, notepad++, guliverkli do not have diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that most industry strength software is written without design diagrams, class diagrams and/or other UML style documentation.

Why? Because most experienced developers (including me) do not see enough value/cost benefits from doing it.

Developers are relatively quick to adapt tools that are practical and helpful (test tools, source control, code analyzers, profilers etc.) so it is not a question of developers being "old dogs" and/or not wanting to improve the tools they use. If design diagrams etc. actually helped speed up development and/or improved product quality then it would be used a lot more than it is. However it doesn't so it isn't. And this is despite 30+ years of "guru" after "guru" trying to push yet another box/sphere/line tool down developers throat :-)